# ¿Como evito que aparezcan las imágenes detras del header?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Cuando bajo en la web se puede apreciar de una madera casi invisible pero poco estética las imágenes detrás del header cuando este eta encogido (ya que estando expandido las imágenes aparecen sobre el). La pregunta es seria mas precisamente, ¿Como desaparezco o movilizo las imágenes al momento de encoger el header?

Asi:

[image: Header en estado normal]

[image: Header encogido]

El código es este: (Aunque da problema al ejecutar y hacer scroll debido a un error que desconozco, por lo tanto no se puede apreciar el error aquí)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $('header').addClass('header2');
    } else {
      $('header').removeClass('header2');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body {
  /*propiedades del cuerpo*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Imprima', sans-serif;
  color: #666;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.logo1 {
  /*posicion logo 1*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}

.logo1 .header2 {
  /*posicion logo 1*/
  visibility: hidden;
}

.logo2 {
  /*posicion logo 1*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 100px;
}

.logo2 .header2 {
  /*posicion logo 1*/
  visibility: hidden;
}

header {
  /*propiedades del header*/
  background: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.whrapper {
  /*espaciado margen general*/
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#logo-header {
  /*Propiedades generales del titulo y descripcion de la pagina*/
  position: static;
  margin-top: -10px
}

#logo-header .nombre-pagina {
  /*propiedades del titulo de la pagina*/
  /*Texto: HABITACION DINAMICA*/
  display: block;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: white;
}

#logo-header .descripcion-pagina {
  /*propiedades de la descripcion de la pagina*/
  /*Texto: Controlador*/
  display: block;
  font-weight: 350;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #999;
}

header nav {
  /*propiedades de la barra de navegacion*/
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

header nav a {
  /*propiedades de los botones de navegacion*/
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: color 0.1s linear 0.1s;
}

header nav a:hover {
  color: #f2a643;
  background: #4c4c4c;
}


/*
EMPIEZA HEADER 2
*/

.header2 {
  position: fixed;
  height: 75px;
}

.header2 nav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: -65px;
}

.header2 nav a {
  transition: color 0.1s linear 0.1s;
}


/*
TERMINA HEADER 2
*/


/*
EMPIEZA AREA DE CONTENIDO
*/

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.header2+.contenido {
  padding-top: 75px;
}

.contenido .tabla-contenido table {
  position: static;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.contenido .tabla-contenido table p:before {
  content: "APAGADO";
  color: #c1877a;
}

.contenido .tabla-contenido table p:hover:before {
  content: "ENCENDER";
  color: #f4d742;
  transition: color 0.1s linear 0.1s;
}

.contenido .tabla-contenido table p.presionado:before {
  content: "ENCENDIDO";
  color: #42f462;
}


/*
TERMINA AREA DE CONTENIDO
*/

#footer {
  /*propiedades del footer*/
  background: #333;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

#footer .contenidofooter {
  font-family: 'Imprima', sans-serif;
  color: lightgray;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Habitacion Dinamica</title>

  <link href="HabitacionDinamica.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="header.js"></script>
  <script src="texto.js"></script>


  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Imprima" rel="stylesheet">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <div class="logo1">
    <img src="Escudo50.jpg" width="85px" height="70px" />
  </div>
  <div class="logo2">
    <img src="PacMan.png" width="70px" height="70px" />
  </div>

</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div id="logo-header">
      <div class="whrapper">
        <span class="nombre-pagina">HABITACION DINAMICA</span>
        <span class="descripcion-pagina">Controlador</span>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <a href="tal">CONTROLADOR</a>
        <a href="tal">ACERCA DE</a>
      </nav>
    </div>

  </header>

  <section class="contenido">

    <center>
      <br>
      <font color="#0D7619">
        <h2>
          <center><a name="habitacion">HABITACIÓN</a></center>
        </h2>
      </font>
      <br>
      <img src="MapaEjemplo.png">
    </center>

    <div class="tabla-contenido">
      <center>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>APARATO</td>
            <td>ENCENDIDO/APAGADO</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>LAMPARA</td>
            <td>
              <a href="#">
                <p class="APAGADO"></p>
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>LUCES</td>
            <td>
              <a href="#">
                <p class="APAGADO"></p>
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>TV</td>
            <td>
              <a href="#">
                <p class="APAGADO"></p>
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>VENTILADOR</td>
            <td>
              <a href="#">
                <p class="APAGADO"></p>
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>EQUIPO DE SONIDO</td>
            <td>
              <a href="#">
                <p class="APAGADO"></p>
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </center>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
  </section>

</body>
<div id="footer">
  <footer>
    <div class="contenidofooter">
      Pagina por Elder Vielman
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

En la funcion que modifica el header:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
            $('header').addClass('header2');
        } else {
            $('header').removeClass('header2');
        }
    });
});
```

Tambien debes incluir codigo para modificar la clase de "logo1" y "logo2". Ejemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
            $('header').addClass('header2');
            $('.logo1,.logo2').addClass('header2')
        } else {
            $('header').removeClass('header2');
            $('.logo1,.logo2').removeClass('header2')
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Y también tiene que cambiar el CSS porque ahora mismo tiene `.logo1 .header2` y `.logo2 .header2`, añadir la clase `header2` a los logos no hará nada ya que eso actuaría sobre los hijos de logo1 y 2 con clase `header2` (cosa que no tiene). Debería tener: `.logo1.header2` y `.logo2.header2` sin espacios entre clases